# Determine if a value is present between two dates

Tags: sql-server

This sounds very easy, but it's also not. I have the following query

```
SELECT 
*
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        p.ForeName, p.SurName, p.Community, MAX(cr.DateRec) as “LastDate”,
        DATEDIFF(Day, MAX(cr.DateRec), SYSDATETIME()) AS “Days”
    FROM
        [HygieneInfo] h
    INNER JOIN 
        [CareRecs] cr ON cr.CareRecID = h.CareRecIDs
    INNER JOIN
        [Patients] p ON p.PatientID = h.ServiceUserID
    WHERE (h.TypeOfWash in (‘2’, ‘3’))
    AND (cr.AnswerType not in (‘2’,’3’,’4’))
    GROUP BY p.ForeName, p.SurName, p.Community
) SUB
WHERE Days >= 6
ORDER BY Days, SUB.SurName ASC
```

The query takes info from three tables, [Patients] (patient info), [CareRecs] (care records) and [HygieneInfo] (records of baths, showers and personal hygiene that holds additional information about the record held in [CareRecs], eg whether it was a bath / shower, whether the temp was checked, etc).

This produces a list of results like this (the data hasn't been refreshed for a few days, hence the larger numbers):

[image: list of results]

However, within [CareRecs] there is a field 'AnswerType' which if 2 - 4 denotes either declined, not possible or outright refused to undertake the action. I've included it in the code here to enable me to obtain the gap in days to today's date since a last bath / shower.

What would be of help is to determine that in that amount of time (GapDays), whether or not there has been an unsuccessful attempt to assist that person to have a bath / shower, so that a "Declined?" column could be at the end of each returned row, saying YES for any occasions where 2, 3 or 4 were entered, or NO if there haven't.

Can anyone assist me? I was thinking something like

```
MAX(CASE WHEN cr.AnswerType IN ('2', '3','4'
then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as "Declined?"
```

But this doesn't seem to quite work right, in that it appears to only give me a YES if there are ANY 2,3,4s in any of the records for that person, regardless of whether they're during the gap between the last successfully recorded and now.

Any assistance given would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT - I've been asked for some sample data. It's difficult to know which rows will demonstrate the issue, but here we go:

[HygieneInfo] Table:

```
    ServiceUserID, CareRecIDs, TypeOfWash, TemperatureChecked, Deleted
    0c50b0a3-0472-4f59-83aa-6a86cf7e362e,cd573731-0382-49fd-97bb-12a7b7ce2ee0,1,FALSE, 0, 
4a8f35c1-3cc3-45d1-bc13-09cc55a4ffb1,9cf202d2-afb3-4770-9b3c-3211b290210d,2,FALSE,0,
05516352-590d-4240-8ab1-07ca2932cc05,3eb60837-712e-4037-9e78-ee5d6d49c796,1,FALSE,0,
ec6fd618-7e33-48f7-9690-08a1a940fa80,d9ab62ce-9127-44cc-b7e6-a065ace8333d,1,FALSE,0,
b5eb874a-a563-4814-b765-836e837b28c9,68eeb3e6-c6fc-438f-bbe8-b3985fccc038,1,FALSE,0
```

[CareRecs] Table:

```
CareRecID, ADLName, AnswerType, ServiceUserID, SliderData, DateRec,

68eeb3e6-c6fc-438f-bbe8-b3985fccc038,Personal care,1,b5eb874a-a563-4814-b765-836e837b28c9,Wash,2020-07-19T08:57:21,
cd573731-0382-49fd-97bb-12a7b7ce2ee0,Personal care,1,0c50b0a3-0472-4f59-83aa-6a86cf7e362e,Wash,2020-07-16T09:46:57,
3eb60837-712e-4037-9e78-ee5d6d49c796,Personal care,1,05516352-590d-4240-8ab1-07ca2932cc05,Wash,2020-07-18T11:04:15,
9cf202d2-afb3-4770-9b3c-3211b290210d,Personal care,1,4a8f35c1-3cc3-45d1-bc13-09cc55a4ffb1,Shower,2020-07-14T15:06:29,
d9ab62ce-9127-44cc-b7e6-a065ace8333d,Personal care,1,ec6fd618-7e33-48f7-9690-08a1a940fa80,Wash,2020-07-13T08:14:13
```

[Patients] Table:

ForeName, Surname, DateOfBirth, PatientID,

```
Harry,Patient,1924-03-24,ec6fd618-7e33-48f7-9690-08a1a940fa80
Peter,Patient,1947-05-16,0c50b0a3-0472-4f59-83aa-6a86cf7e362e
Audrey,Patient,1931-04-19,05516352-590d-4240-8ab1-07ca2932cc05
Margaret,Patient,1938-09-05,4a8f35c1-3cc3-45d1-bc13-09cc55a4ffb1
James,Patient,1936-05-27,mb5eb874a-a563-4814-b765-836e837b28c9
```

The idea being that one of these patients may go at least 6 days between TypeOfWash 2 or 3, and during that time there may be a AnswerType of 2 / 4 (or 3).

Comment: **Consumable** sample data (not an image) along with expected results well help us help you here.

Comment: I was hoping to get away with not having to do this, as it would mean having to anonymise the data. If it's impossible without this, then I'll do my best.

Comment: It only has to be sample data, not anonymised. If the Surname and Community aren't relevant to the question, they don't need to be in your sample, for example

Comment: @Lamu https://gofile.io/d/wFfmYt I've stripped out surnames, locations and also removed most fields that are of no use in this example. Thanks

Comment: [Edit] your question, put the data in there (not a hyperlink). I am not going to download an unknown file, from an unknown person, from a site I don't know, and neither will many others. Many users  here (IT) professions and know far too well the dangers of opening strange links.

Comment: You can always count on the good people of SO to make you feel about an inch tall....Sadly there are many, many records involved here. I'm unsure therefore of any other method that will allow the data to be seen

Comment: If you have "many" rows then it's not a sample, Dan. I'm not sure how I'm making you feel an inch tall, however. A basic part of internet security, I'm afraid, is to not open and download files you don't know; that's nothing against you that's just common sense. Especially when many of us use Stack Overflow in work environments and so we need to be *very* careful on what we download.

Comment: I understand that, and I should've thought that through but was focussed on trying to get the data sorted and didn't apply common sense. Perhaps I was being sensitive, but a simple "sorry Dan, no offence but I'll not be clicking that link. You could be sending me anything. Is there no way you can upload some of the data here?" would have sufficed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CASE` statements to get the max of the 2 dates, and if the refusal date is after the other date, then there is a refusal:

```
SELECT 
*   
,CASE WHEN LastDateRefused>LastDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as isRefused
,DATEDIFF(Day, LastDate, SYSDATETIME()) AS Days
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        p.ForeName, 
        p.SurName,  
        MAX(CASE WHEN cr.AnswerType not in (2,3,4) THEN cr.DateRec END) as LastDate,
        MAX(CASE WHEN cr.AnswerType in (2,3,4) THEN cr.DateRec END) as LastDateRefused
 
    FROM
        [HygieneInfo] h
    INNER JOIN 
        [CareRecs] cr ON cr.CareRecID = h.CareRecIDs
    INNER JOIN
        [Patients] p ON p.PatientID = h.ServiceUserID
    WHERE (h.TypeOfWash in (2,3))
    --AND (cr.AnswerType not in (2,3,4))
    GROUP BY p.ForeName, p.SurName
) SUB
WHERE DATEDIFF(Day, LastDate, SYSDATETIME())  >= 6
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This gives me even more than I thought I wanted, which was the date of their last refusal (whenever that was), as well as within the timeframe. Although my background is IT, this isn't my job and so was slowly stumbling along to this kind of answer myself, but you've given me that last 30% and a bit more! Thank you very much for your help.